# Subfloat problem

Tags: subfloats

Here's my code. I can't understanding what it's missing due to the error:

File ended while scanning use of \sf@@@subfloat.

My idea is to have a series of the images with subcaptions (a) (b) and (c)

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}




\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[\emph{(a)}]
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/conf1} \quad
        \subfloat[\emph{(b)}]
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/conf2} \quad
            \subfloat[\emph{(c)}]
            {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/conf3} 
                \caption{Fiber configuration of (a) unidirectional tape, (b) eight-harness satin weave, and (c) plain weave.}
            \end{figure}
        
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you have unbalanced braces -- the closing one after each mandatory arg of `\subfloat` is missing (I didn't test your example, though)

Comment: Thank you Arash. Silly mistake by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need the package `\usepackage{graphicx}`
Then the curly braces after `\includegraphics`

This should work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/conf1}} \quad
            \subfloat[]
            {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/conf2}} \quad
                \subfloat[]
                {\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Immagini/conf3}} 
                    \caption{Fiber configuration of (a) unidirectional tape, (b) eight-harness satin weave, and (c) plain weave.}
                \end{figure}
                
            \end{document}
```

N.B. I also removed the `\emph{(a)}` it double the "a" in the subcaption

Comment: Thank you. It works!

Comment: perfect! Do not forget to accept the answer clicking on the check sign and, eventually, to upvote it if you think it was useful.